# Does the following implication always hold in probabilty theory?

Tags: probability

Suppose A and B are two possible events and it is given  that the conditional probability $P(A\mid B)$  tends to zero .Can we always infer from this ,without any further information, that $P(B\mid A)$  also tends to zero? If this is not the case can you please provide some counterexample?

Comment: What about the case where $P(A|B)=0$ and $P(B|A) \neq 0$? There are plenty of example like this.

Comment: @mtiano Could you provide an example of events $A$ and $B$ such that $P(A), P(B) > 0$, $P(A\mid B) = 0$, and $P(B\mid A) > 0$?  Wouldn't Bayes' theorem suggest that $P(B\mid A) = P(A\mid B)P(B)/P(A)$ is $0$ whenever $P(A\mid B) = 0$?

Comment: I am interested in the case when P(A|B) is very small.Assume A is the event that the universe is governed by natural laws only and B the event that it is life-friendly .The fine tuning argument in physics(or theology!) assumes P(A|B) is very small and then jump (erroneosly) to the conclusion that P(B|A )is also  very small.That is where the untruth of this implication becomes crucial !

Comment: @DilipSarwate I can't give the example you request, your reasoning is correct. The original post did not give the requirements $P(A),P(B)>0$. With the addition imposition the examples I suggest are impossible.

Comment: Hint: What if $P(B)=1$ and $P(A)$ is very small?

Comment: @mtiano the original post did reqiure that P(A),P(B)>0.What does it mean for an event to be POSSIBLE!

Answer (score 0):

p(a|b)*p(b) = p(b|a)*p(a) (bayes)

Let's say p(b) is really big and p(a) is really small. Out of the above equations then follows that p(a|b) tends to zero but p(b|a) will tend to 1...

for example, let's say you chose a number between 1-10 and p(b) is the chance of that number beeing smaller or equal to 9. From that follows that p(b) = 90%
Let's say p(a) is the chance that that number is exactly 1 => p(a) = 10%.

p(a|b) = 1/9
p(b|a) = 1